# What happens if The Flash trips?

Tags: dc, the-flash

What happens if The Flash trips?

Does perpetual motion cause him to safely not fall, does he die, does his speed when crashing cause environmental damage?

Comment: if he's faster than the escape velocity of Earth, this happens: http://img1.joyreactor.com/pics/post/flash-comic-dragonarte-DC-Comics-1256249.png

Answer (score 6):

He trips in *Justice League* (2017) on the stairs, he does not fall safely, does not die but there does appear to be some environmental damage and things get sparky. This is where he ends up on the floor and there looks to be some damage around him though I'm not sure if he caused it or if it was already there.

[image: The Flash on the ground after having tripped over]

You can watch the scene here:

Answer (score 2):

In the cartoon Batman: The Brave and the Bold, Flash got into a fight with Reverse Flash and defeated him by tripping him. You can see it in this clip.

It looks like the uploader of that video has disabled playing on other sites, and clicking through to YouTube doesn't preserve the timestamp. You can [skip to about 5:15](https://youtu.be/-GilhCdohGA?t=315) to see it.

I assume Reverse Flash counts for your answer because in this fight, they move at roughly the same speed. It looks consistent with the Justice League [answer left by TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/210795/75082) in that once tripped, the laws of physics take over. Don't ask me how Flash running his hand on the rock wall creates ice though...